# Jquery - operators in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators, if-statement

I'm trying to submit a form to a different location depending on which (of two) form fields have been filed in.

It work when both fields have a value but when only one if field has a value it always submits to the suppliers/category/ URL. Here is my code.

```
$('#suppliersForm').submit(function() {

catVal = $('#category').val()
keywordVal = $('#keywords').val()

if( $('#category').val() && $('#keywords').val() ) 
{
var searchString = 'http://<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name#</cfoutput>/suppliers/searchresults/' + catVal + '/' + keywordVal
window.location.replace(searchString);
}
else if( $('#category').val() || $('#keywords').val() )
{   
var searchString = 'http://<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name#</cfoutput>/suppliers/category/' + catVal
window.location.replace(searchString);  
}
else if( $('#keywords').val() || $('#category').val() )
{   
var searchString = 'http://<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name#</cfoutput>/suppliers/keywords/' + keywordVal
window.location.replace(searchString);  
}
return false;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you dont understand the && (AND) and ||(OR) operators. && runs if both statements are true. || runs when one or both statements are true. If one field is left empty the second else if (suppliers/category) will always run. In fact the thirth else if will never run.

Comment: your right, I didn't fully understand what the || operator did. Is there a way making this work?

Comment: btw you can check if the value catVal or keywordVal is set, then you don't have to get $('#category').val() or $('#keywords').val() in every if statement. btw dont forget to close this catVal = $('#category').val() with a ;

Comment: depends on what you want? Do you want the value of #category to be a certain thing when the second if runs? Be more specific in you question.

Comment: thanks for your help. I understand the operators a little better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#suppliersForm').submit(function() {

var catVal = $('#category').val();
var keywordVal = $('#keywords').val();
var searchString = "";

if( catVal != "" && keywordVal !="" ) 
{
     searchString = 'http://<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name#</cfoutput>/suppliers/searchresults/' + catVal + '/' + keywordVal;
}
else if( catVal != ""  )
{   
     searchString = 'http://<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name#</cfoutput>/suppliers/category/' + catVal;
}
else if( keywordVal != "" )
{   
     searchString = 'http://<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name#</cfoutput>/suppliers/keywords/' + keywordVal;
}
window.location.replace(searchString);  
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second checks on both else if:

```
else if( $('#category').val() || $('#keywords').val() ) --> else if( $('#category').val() )
else if( $('#keywords').val() || $('#category').val() ) --> else if( $('#keywords').val() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no difference between

```
else if( $('#category').val() || $('#keywords').val() )
```

and

```
else if( $('#keywords').val() || $('#category').val() )
```

So if at least one field contains some value the first else if is executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery('#suppliersForm').click(function(event){       

    var searchString = '';
    var catVal  = $('#category').val();
    var keywordVal = $('#keywords').val();



    if( catVal.length > 0 && keywordVal.length > 0 ){
        searchString = 'http://<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name#</cfoutput>/suppliers/searchresults/' + catVal + '/' + keywordVal;
    } else if( catVal.length > 0 ) {
        searchString = 'http://<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name#</cfoutput>/suppliers/category/' + catVal;
    } else if( keywordVal.length > 0  ) {
        searchString = 'http://<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name#</cfoutput>/suppliers/keywords/' + keywordVal
    } else {
        alert( 'Please enter at least on value' );   
    }


    window.location.replace(searchString);  

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8AUZ/

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably make it much more concise like this:

```
var catVal = $('#category').val()
,   keywordVal = $('#keywords').val()
,   searchString = 'http://<cfoutput>#cgi.server_name#</cfoutput>/suppliers/';

if( catVal && keywordVal ) 
    searchString += ('searchresults/' + catVal + '/' + keywordVal);
else if( catVal )
    searchString += ('category/' + catVal);
else if( keywordVal )
    searchString += ('keyword/' + keywordVal);
else return;

window.location.replace(searchString);
return false;
```